# How to print a local file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to print local file using phonegap application.File may be image,pdf,doc,xls etc. Please suggest be how can I implement this feature using phonegap .
Thanks

Comment: Print means to Printer Device or Screen ?

Comment: @ManjeshV thanks for quick reply ,I want to print file using printer device

Comment: Look at this plugins [Git Phonegap Plugins](https://github.com/paulb777/phonegap-plugins)

Comment: @ManjeshV there is no plugin to print file